# Edit a Widget in Kv

Tags: python-3.x, widget, kivy, kivy-language

I have a widget that I defined in Kv language, which exists within a layout that I also defined in Kv language. I would like to change the text of the widget in the layout in Kv. How would I go about is?

Python code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Test(BoxLayout):
    pass


class KivyTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


app = KivyTestApp()
app.run()
```

Kv code:

```
<Header@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint_y: 0.2

    Button:
        text: 'Button 1'
    Button:
        id: edit_but

<Test>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Header:
        edit_but.text: 'Button 2'
        # How do I do this ^ ?
    Label:
        text: 'Filler'
```

Comment: You can use [ids](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids) to access the `Widget` to be edited.

Comment: That did not work. I changed `edit_but.text` to `self.ids.edit_but.text` and `root.ids.edit_but.text` but both gave me the `Invalid property name` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `kv`, you can add a `Property` to your `Header` rule (I named it `edit_text`). That property can be used to set the text of the `Button` by using `text: root.edit_text`. That `Property` can be set whenever you use the `Header` in `kv` as `edit_text: 'Button 2'`:

```
<Header@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint_y: 0.2
    edit_text: ''

    Button:
        text: 'Button 1'
    Button:
        id: edit_but
        text: root.edit_text

<Test>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Header:
        edit_text: 'Button 2'
        # How do I do this ^ ?
    Label:
        text: 'Filler'
```